# Are there times when convergence tests contradict each other?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In my Calc II class, we're just starting convergence tests and all the examples are very convinient and they work perfectly (obviously, since they are examples), but my professor couldn't really answer my question.

Is there a time, or some examples, where convergence tests will contradict each other? Like the ratio test says the series will converge, but the limit comparison test says it diverges, etc.

And if there are examples, how would I know which one is correct?

Again, sorry if this is trivial...

Comment: The more frequent case is that all but one test yields inconclusive results...

Comment: No. Mathematics is consistent so, if you solve the same problem in two ways and don't make any errors, you will get the same answer. Of course, as JM says, it is quite common that you may try two methods and find that only one of them gives an answer, while the other is inconclusive.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer As far as we know, mathematics is consistent :)

Comment: If math is inconsistent, see http://www.xkcd.com/816/ for what to do next.

Comment: If you get far enough with math to reach analysis, you'll be able to see why the answer is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They should never contradict one another.  The worst that could happen is that one test is inconclusive while another definitively shows that the limit does or does not exist.

Comment: Well, the very *worst* that can happen is that all the tests we try are inconclusive... (-:

Comment: Ha, that's very true.